# MCP 1.8.8 Not Compiling

Tags: java, minecraft

I am new to Minecraft modding, and I started using MCP 918 with eclipse and i am having trouble compiling it. It keeps saying "package javax.jnlp does not exist". I already downloaded and added the jnlp.jar file to my build path in eclipse. I can't find any solutions on the web and i have tried almost every solution I could find on the internet and none of them worked. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[Recompile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Hsj.png)

As I said before I tried almost everything. I even added the jar to my class path. My client can also run in eclipse with no errors.

Comment: providing screenshots of error wouldn't help please post in actual text ,read [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)